# Scifi book with battle spaceships and humanoid cat people who have eyes that change colors with their mood?

Tags: books, spaceship, cyborg, story-identification

Does anyone know this book? It starts with a space captain and his ship and crew being attacked by another ship. Eventually the ship was so damaged that they had to board another ship after fleeing (or maybe it just showed up and helped attack).

The inhabitants of the other ship were cat people, humanoids whose eye colors changed with their mood. Green for amusement, black for death, red for anger... There is a female doctor from the destroyed ship that has a brief eye flirtation with one of the cat humanoid officers but they both know a romance would be frowned upon.

The cat humanoids also had a thing where if they got angry they would attack and lose control if they reached a no return point or "killing edge" which got activated a couple times having the humans on board. At one point someone was also "spaced" or they were ejected from the ship aka executed for it (one of the cat people).

Eventually something happens and they are all captured and the cat captain is injured. The cat humanoid captain is injured and the female doctor treats him in the prison cell. At the end the captain finds out that he is a synth of the real captain and hides it I think either because being one is taboo.

I've kept thinking that this book was called *Battleship* something but cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Both Larry Niven's the Ringworld series and Star Trek have spaceships and cat people, but I can't remember any similar story in either. Of course in ST it could be one of the bazillion paperback novels, but who knows.

Comment: Possibly one of C. J. Cherryh's novels? Were the aliens called the "iduve" in this story?

Comment: Was it a merchantman or military spaceship?

Answer (score 1):

[*Darkship Thieves*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6605730-darkship-thieves) by Sara A. Hoyt.

> Athena Hera Sinistra never wanted to go to space. Never wanted see the eerie glow of the Powerpods. Never wanted to visit Circum Terra. Never had any interest in finding out the truth about the DarkShips. You always get what you don't ask for. Which must have been why she woke up in the dark of shipnight, within the greater night of space in her father's space cruiser, knowing that there was a stranger in her room. In a short time, after taking out the stranger--who turned out to be one of her father's bodyguards up to no good, she was hurtling away from the ship in a lifeboat to get help. But what she got instead would be the adventure of a lifetime--if" she managed to survive. . .

Comment: I don't see anything in this answer that shows a connection to the original question. Who knows this could be the book, but every part of the Question relates to a ship of Cat People or a Felinoid type humans. The Answer does not show any correlation to the question.

Comment: No mention on [the TV Tropes entry](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/DarkshipThieves) either, and usually they're all over cat people...